# How to change the size of the button and add back ground color to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to change the size of the add document button, I changed the size but the plus image beside it remains the same. I also want to add background color to it to make it look more like a button. Please advise.

This is the current code I have.

```
<style>
.ms-addnew {
font-size: 20pt ! important;
}
</style>
```

For reference, https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBTse.jpg   
Button look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObkuW.jpg

Comment: Could we have some HTML too please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll need a code sample to help you better, I tried to recreate button similar to the image that you provided us like so:

**HTML:**

```
<button class='btn-info'>Post your question</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn-info {
  background: #07a3f7;
  color: #fff;

  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;

  font-size: 18px;

  padding: 15px 25px;
}

.btn-info:hover{
 background: #0572ad;
 transition: 0.8s background;
}
```

If you're using a **library**, the **custom styles** might not take effect because the **library** is interfering.

You can check with this **code sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zo2eq65g/)**.

You can learn more about `:hover` **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)**.

Comment: Hi Manuel Abascal, thank you for the sample codes. How do I add in a hover effect to darken the button?

Answer (score 1):

Use need to use [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width), [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) & [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).

```
.ms-addnew {
  ...
  width: <value>;
  height: <value>;
  background-color: <value>;
}
```

Comment: Hi explorer, I tried but it colored the entire background reference:https://imgur.com/a/6H9LmzF

I tried using 'color: white;' to change the text color but that didn't work.
please advise.

Comment: Using CSS, background of an element can be specified & also `color` of text can be specified. You need to post HTML code to provide specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try bootstrap CSS.

Demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("span:contains('new document')").addClass("badge badge-primary")
        })
    </script>
```

[image]

Update:

The script apply bootstrap CSS to the span element, you could use developer tool to check the text(new document) matches, and you could debug it if you familiar with JS.

[image]

Comment: Hi Lee_MSFT, I'm not sure why but I added the codes in a script editor and they didn't change anything.